# How can I force a content type on the response?

Tags: xml, postman, content-type

I use an API which returns `text/plain` for its content type even though it's actually `application/xml` (XML format). If I change the content type dropdown in Postman to XML, it displays in the "Pretty" tab properly.

I have also tried setting `Accept` to `application/xml` but the API still returns the document as `text/plain`.

Since the API doesn't return the correct `Content-Type` header, how can I force Postman to show it as if it were `application/xml`?

I thought a Pre-request Script might work? But I am new to Postman scripting and have not discovered an answer by Googling around.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following as a header, when you send your request:

> Determine what type of representation is desired on the client-side, an HTTP header ACCEPT is used

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Accept | application/xml |

Read the following: [REST API Content Negotiation](https://restfulapi.net/content-negotiation/)

Comment: Ahh shoot, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried this and it still returns text/plain. I will update my question.

Comment: Is your api public, or a similar one to see if I can help with your query

Comment: I am using the [DynaDot](https://www.dynadot.com/domain/api3.html) API. You can register for a free account and get an API key. If you make a query to it no matter what it responds with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`.